# How long the script executed using UIWebView-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString will be available?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

What is the lifetime of Javascript code used with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`?

I found some code repeatedly using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with same script and with no page reloads in between. Is that good to do ?

Is the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` injects the entire script in to active page in `UIWebView` and make it available till reload or navigate to another page ?

Is there any apple documentation regarding the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code injected will be available throughout the life of the current page loaded in the `UIWebView`. That is, if called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with some script, that will be available till a new page is loaded in the `UIWebView` or the page is refreshed. No need to inject the entire script every time to evaluate something using the same.

Checked it with injecting some functions first and called the functions (only) later.